# What is the Visual basic version of Signalr Proxy.On Method

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

What is the Visual basic equivalent of this code for a Signalr Proxy Hub?

```
  proxy.On<ChatMessage>("broadcastMessage", OnMessage);
```

I have Tried..

```
 proxy.On(Of ChatMessage)("broadcastMessage", OnMessage)
```

But Get an error stating: Expression does not produce a value.

Also Tried..

```
proxy.On(Of ChatMessage)("broadcastMessage", Sub() OnMessage())
```

But it never calls my method because it takes a parameter of ChatMessage Object.

```
Private Sub OnMessage(Msg As ChatMessage)
   Dim NewMsg As ChatMessage = Msg
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use 'addressOf' in place of 'Sub()' for this line.

```
proxy.On(Of ChatMessage)("broadcastMessage", Sub() OnMessage())
```

Like...

```
proxy.On(Of ChatMessage)("broadcastMessage", AddressOf OnMessage)
```